# multiplying each element of a list using n-values in netlogo

Tags: list, netlogo

any ideas on how I can multiply each element of a list by 2 using `n-values` function (instead of `map`) in netlogo?

say my code is the following:

```
let mylist n-values 10 [?]
let mylist2 fput -1 lput 10 mylist
```

how can I modify `mylist2` so that its each item is doubled - but using `n-values`?

many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you'd use `n-values` to double the elements when initially creating the list. You don't really use `n-values` to modify the list afterwards. `map` is much better for that. Anyway, doubling the initial list looks like:

```
let mylist n-values 10 [ 2 * ? ]
let mylist2 fput -2 lput 20 mylist
```

If you want to *just* double `mylist2`, you *should* use `map`:

```
let mylist2 map [ 2 * ? ] (fput -2 lput 20 mylist)
```

Update:

So, sounds like this is for an assignment or something. In that case, you can do it using `n-values` and `item`, but I'll let you work out the details ;)

Comment: thanks! I am aware of these options; but I do need to use n-values to change the second list somehow. I understand that it is not necessary to change it that way, but is it possible to do it? is there any way to do it?

Comment: @dotthei Well you could do that as `n-values 12 [2 * (? - 1)]`, but please explain what you are actually trying to accomplish.  Why avoid `map`?

Comment: @dotthei If this is homework, you should probably think it through yourself.

Comment: There is no such thing as "modifying" lists in NetLogo, only creating new lists, perhaps based on old ones.